# delimiter error

Tags: delimiters

I don't know what's wrong with this code. I tried and it seems that the extreme "\bigg"s (the first and the last one) cause delimiter error.

```
    \begin{equation}
    \lim_{\rho\rightarrow0}
    \biggl⁡[\frac{(-\rho)^{\gamma-\beta-1}}{(z-1)^{\alpha}}\biggl[\ln⁡\rho 
    \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i(\gamma-\beta)\varphi} 
    d\varphi+i\int_{0}^{2\pi}\varphi e^{i(\gamma-
    \beta)\varphi}d\varphi\biggr]\biggr]
    \end{equation}
```

Comment: I've marked up your code: I assume that the surrounding `$` tokens were there expecting MathJax (we don't use it), so I've removed them.

Comment: Copy-pasting your code into my editor, there seem to be some 'odd' invisible characters after the first `\biggl`. Could you try deleting from there to the `[` and re-typing that part?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a spurious character between \biggl and [

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you need to remove the "invisible" (and presumably unwanted) characters in `\biggl⁡[\frac` and `biggl[\ln⁡\rho`. In addition, to make the equation more easily parsable "by eye", you may want to

- reduce the space between the integral symbols and the integrands, and
- increase the space between the integrands and the `d\varphi` terms.

In short, something like

```
\begin{equation}
   \lim_{\rho\to0}
   \biggl[\frac{(-\rho)^{\gamma-\beta-1}}{(z-1)^{\alpha}}\biggl[
   \ln\rho \int_{0}^{2\pi}\!\!e^{i(\gamma-\beta)\varphi} \,d\varphi+
   i\int_{0}^{2\pi}\!\!\varphi e^{i(\gamma-\beta)\varphi}\,d\varphi
   \biggr]\biggr]
\end{equation}
```